# Run application on Lock Screen at the center of screen

Tags: c#, uwp, lockscreen

I have a UWP music player application. I want this application to run in lock screen (Windows + L).

So is there any way to show specific XAML page when screen is locked. Currently I am using toast notifications to do this. but problem with toast notification is that I don't have much control on UI.

Answer (score 0):

So if I'm understanding you correctly, you'd like to have a UWP app that can be manipulated while the machine is locked. You want your app to have an interface on top of the lock screen.

If I'm correct about what you're trying to do, then I don't believe that this is currently possible with the UWP platform.

From the [LockScreen documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/schemas/appxpackage/appxmanifestschema/element-lockscreen)

> An app can reflect three different types of information to the lock
>   screen:
>
> - The app tile's current badge
> - The text from the app tile's most recent
> - tile notification Toast notifications

Unfortunately for us dreamers, myself included, there's a lot of limitations intentionally built in to the UWP platform that arbitrarily handicaps it. This seems to be yet another one of these limitations.

If you feel like this would be useful to you and others, feel free to recommend it here https://wpdev.uservoice.com/forums/110705-universal-windows-platform

Comment: What is the use-case for controlling a app on the lock screen.  It's defeat the purpose of locking the screen.  And this is not a limitation of UWP itself.

Comment: @BlackFrog the purpose is this very question. The OP built a media player app, that he wants the user to be able to control if the computer locks. That sounds pretty legitimate to me. And it's 100% a limitation of the framework. It was a conscious choice to restrict apps in that way.

Comment: From the beginning of Window 3.1 they never allowed that use-case. I understand that would be a cool feature. I understand on a mobile you can skip to the next song, it’s a different use-case because the device mostly likely would be with you. Having a app that by-pass a security feature on Windows is not a limitation of UWP, that is a feature of Security.

Comment: No I agree it's a security feature. That said, I think that since UWP can be on any device they should have an api for pushing simple controls to the lock screen for cases just like this. It should def be limited, but not being able to do this when other platforms can, makes uwp less attractive to everyone.